# Can't delete file and folder from my desktop

Tags: files, directory, delete

Hello i'm new ubuntu user so here my problem,
i can't delete file and folder from my desktop there is no option for that."Move to trash" is not optional on list when i press right click.

Comment: Can you show the results of this command in your question: `cd ~/Desktop && ls -l`

Answer (score 4):

I really wanted to write this as a comment but I don't have enough rep, mods and others be merciful

In ubuntu the concept of "delete" from windows is "Move to Trash" as far as the desktop is concerned.

This can also be achieved by just highlighting the item you want gone and hitting the delete key. If you want it permanently gone and not hang around in the trash folder use Shift + delete.

Is the Move To Trash not even in the options list? what happens when you hit the delete key ?

Comment: nothing happens when i hit delete key.And when i try to create new folder it says "There was an error creating the directory in /home/danilo/Desktop." and same thing for moving some thing to desktop. Can u help me?

Comment: hmmm, can u fire up a terminal and try mkdir or rm? see what happens?

Comment: I saw that on web and not working.

Comment: I see only this https://www.dropbox.com/s/xptbumh9qovdxp9/Screenshot%20from%202016-03-22%2000%3A08%3A14.jpg?dl=0

Comment: what error message do you get when you attempt to move or delete a file using the terminal?

Comment: No it just give me next line and nothing happends.

Comment: can u screenshot ur terminal or provide a paste of the console?

Comment: Yes here, https://www.dropbox.com/s/oltwzmnx2hrvn1x/Screenshot%20from%202016-03-22%2001%3A03%3A33.png?dl=0

Comment: yes try with sudo, but this is odd because you're not getting a permission denied error, 

hit `ls`
try an `rm`
hit `ls` again, if the lists are different then there is something wrong with ur gui.

if the lists are not different try with sudo, if that works then somehow ur gui user has lost write access on ur desktop . you can then try to fix these permissions with `sudo chmod`

Comment: shouldnt `rm` whine if the file to remove doesn't exist?? @theodorn

Comment: The OP has asked the question again, and seems to be getting help. http://askubuntu.com/questions/748758/how-to-fix-desktop-error-permission-denied

Comment: I find problem.I somehow lock my desktop in settings and i could  do anything on desktop.:D

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround open nautilus (file manager) and go to your `/home/username/Desktop`
 folder. Here you can delete the files.