# How to fix desktop error "Permission denied"

Tags: permissions, files, directory, delete

I can't delete,add and put on desktop files and folder and with everything i only see this. Help me please.

[image]

Comment: Can you add folders and/ or files to your home folder?

Comment: What sort of file is 'Values'?

Comment: Oh,it's text file

Comment: It's not inportent i'm like cut of my desktop i can't even download a image of yours on desktop.

Comment: Can you add the results of this command to your question:`ls -ld $HOME/Desktop`

Comment: I find problem.I somehow lock my desktop in settings and i could  do anything on desktop.:D

Answer (score 2):

Your permissions have probably been messed up. The smallest change that is necessary is:

```
sudo chown danilo /home/danilo/Desktop
```

This should get you access to your Desktop again but more comprehensive changes may be needed if your permissions are more extensively altered from defaults...

Comment: I find problem.I somehow lock my desktop in settings and i could  do anything on desktop.:D

Comment: And this command helped or you solved it another way?

Comment: Yes it helped i just copy-paste to every one because this is not only question i give.