# Ubuntu 20.04 Delete key not deleting files on desktop

Tags: gnome, 20.04

When I am in Nautilus, I can click on a file and press the "delete" key, and it gets sent to the trash. When I click on a file on my desktop and press the "delete" key, nothing happens.

This seems to be new in 20.04; is it a setting I can change?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't delete file and folder from my desktop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/748739/cant-delete-file-and-folder-from-my-desktop)

Comment: @abu_bua No, that looks like a permissions issue, but I can delete it fine from nautilus

Comment: It seems not possible, but you can right click for the context menu and you have the option move to trash.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround open nautilus (file manager) and go to your `/home/username/Desktop`
 folder. Here you can delete the files.

Comment: It's a good workaround, but do you know why it changed or if there's any way to fix it?

Comment: I don't know, I never used the desktop for file placement.

Comment: Best workaround found so far for me : https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231413/basic-desktop-actions-not-available-on-ubuntu-20-04